# how to write to the same file with multiprocessing RLock and Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I met a problem about write to same file with multiprocessing RLock failed.

This is for a linux, Python3.6

```py
#!usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool,RLock

rl=RLock()
f=pd.read_csv('c.csv')

def lifelines(lr): 
    if lr < 10:
        rl.acquire()
        with open('gene.csv', 'a') as out:   # it`s empty
            out.write(str(lr)+'\n')   # it`s empty
        rl.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p=Pool(10, initargs=(rl,))
    for i in range(3,len(f.iloc[0,:])):
        p.apply_async(lifelines,(i,))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

the `gene.csv` is empty

why?

Comment: How do you expect `lr` to be < 0.05? It is taken from an integer sequence that starts at 3. The condition in `lifelines` never evaluates to true in your code. Also, `initargs=(rl,)` on its own has no effect and, in this context, you don't need an `RLock`, a normal `Lock` should suffice.

Comment: Oh, and `print(lr+'\n')` and `out.write(lr+'\n')` will raise TypeErrors for *unsupported operand type(s) for +*, which you don't see because you do not gather and examine the `AsyncResult` objects returned by `apply_async`.

Comment: i want to write what i want data to same file, `lock` will be wrong line

Comment: `lr` may be wrong, i should add `str`, but its not effected final result, its empty...

Comment: The revised code works in both, Windows and Linux, as long as `len(f.iloc[0,:])` is greater than 3. Granted, the lock is pointless under Windows because every worker gets its own lock if done like in your code. Still, `initargs=(rl,)` does absolutely nothing unless you also pass a callable to the `initializer` parameter of the pool's `__init__` and no part of your code acquires the lock recursively, so an `RLock` is really unnecessary.

Comment: thx, @shmee ， I see what you said。    but it still not solve my problem...why is it empty

Comment: We cannot reproduce that behavior because we don't know what that input file `c.csv` looks like. Assign the result of the `apply_async` to a variable, e.g. `r = p.apply_async(lifelines,(i,))` and then do `print(r.get())` directly afterwards while still in the for loop.

Comment: we use `list` to get results which returned, it`s worked.    but we want to find why is empty, no relation to `c.csv`...

Comment: The relation to `c.csv` is that its content determines if your for loop is ever entered or not, i.e. if any task is delegated to the pool. If you already have verified that `len(f.iloc[0,:])` returns a value greater than 3, please mention that. As it stands, I keep working with assumptions because you don't tell me what the outcome of your own tests are.

Comment: The point of the `r = p.apply_async()` stuff I mentioned in my last comment was to see if any exception raises in the worker processes because you wouldn't see them with your code; they would be wrapped inside the `AsyncResult` object that is returned by the `apply_async` method.